# How can I measure the startup performance of release build in react native android?

Tags: android, performance, react-native

I want to know how much time it takes to initial native modules, load js bundle, execute js, etc.
Is there an easy way to this in the release build?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [fabric](https://fabric.io/kits) to check your project performance. Because you can upload your build release in fabric so you can check the performance. You can install `Crashlytics` and `Answers` from fabric. Or maybe you also must to read about [performance](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html) from react native official website.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I need to measure the performance frequently, so fabric won't work for me because upload an build is just too slow. I've read that article about performance too, systrace seems not work on release build.